# Как изменить цвет фона label с нужной геометрией (ширины / высоты)?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qlabel

У меня есть код, где в зависимости от получаемых из **`.тхт`** 
(в **`.тхт`** лежит или `Center` или `Right` или `Left`) данных я хочу закрасить часть монитора (картинки).

Для данной задачи я создал три label:

- `center` - центральная часть картинки
- `left` - левая
- `right` - правая

Когда я изменяю цвет фона в `label`, не смотря на то, что в геометрии прописана одна ширина (высота) при изменении фона расскрашивается намного больше.

Как это можно исправить?

[image: Картинка]

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(343, 253)
        self.left = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.left.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 111, 171))
        self.left.setText("")
        self.left.setObjectName("Left")
        self.center = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.center.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 10, 101, 171))
        self.center.setText("")
        self.center.setObjectName("Center")
        self.monitor = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.monitor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-30, 0, 581, 251))
        self.monitor.setText("")
        self.monitor.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("monitor.png"))
        self.monitor.setObjectName("monitor")
        self.right = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.right.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 10, 111, 171))
        self.right.setText("")
        self.right.setObjectName("Right")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
 
 
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_MainWindow):                     # QDialog  !!!
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)       
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.left, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.center)
        layout.addWidget(self.right)
        
        self.labels = [self.left, self.center, self.right]
    
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.eye_info)
        self.timer.start(200)


    def eye_info(self):
        with open("eye_direction.txt", mode="r") as inputfile:
            eye_direction = inputfile.read()
        for label in self.labels:
            if label.objectName() == eye_direction:
                label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc;")
            else:
                label.setStyleSheet("")
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.press:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.last_pos)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.press = True

        self.last_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.press = False

    def paintEvent(self, event: QtGui.QPaintEvent):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0,1), 1000))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы вставили виджет в `layout`, то уже `layout` управляет геометрией виджета в зависимости от своих политик.

Если вы хотите зафиксировать размера виджета, то

> void QWidget::**setFixedSize**(int w, int h)
>
> Устанавливает ширину виджета w и высоту h.

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(343, 253)
        
        self.left = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
#        self.left.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 111, 171))
        self.left.setText("Left")
        self.left.setObjectName("Left")
        
        self.center = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
#        self.center.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 10, 101, 171))
        self.center.setText("Center")
        self.center.setObjectName("Center")
        
        self.monitor = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.monitor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-30, 0, 581, 251))
        self.monitor.setText("")
        self.monitor.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(50, 50))
        self.monitor.setObjectName("monitor")
        
        self.right = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
#        self.right.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 10, 111, 171))
        self.right.setText("Right")
        self.right.setObjectName("Right")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
 
 
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_MainWindow):                     # QDialog  !!!
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)       
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.left.setFixedSize(70, 70)                                   # +++
        self.center.setFixedSize(70, 70)                                 # +++
        self.right.setFixedSize(70, 70)                                  # +++

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.left, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.center, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)   # +++ AlignCenter
        layout.addWidget(self.right, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)    # +++ AlignCenter
        
        self.labels = [self.left, self.center, self.right]
    
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.eye_info)
        self.timer.start(2000)


    def eye_info(self):
        with open("eye_direction.txt", mode="r") as inputfile:
            eye_direction = inputfile.read()
        for label in self.labels:
            if label.objectName() == eye_direction:
                label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #fcc;")
            else:
                label.setStyleSheet("")
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.press:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.last_pos)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.press = True

        self.last_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.press = False

    def paintEvent(self, event: QtGui.QPaintEvent):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0,1), 1000))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]